# Make a log for any changes in the database

Tags: php

I have a system for school and there are 3 admins in the system.
 so the thing is I want to make a log for each operation made in the system.

for example, if someone added a student I want to see who made it.

so what I have tried so far :

```
<?php
$auth = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT c_id,student_name,auth FROM school WHERE auth = '{$auth}'";
$send_q = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(!$send_q){


  die('rip'.mysqli_error($connection));
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($send_q)){

$c_id= $row['c_id'];
$student_name= $row['student_name'];

echo "<div class='font-w600'>$auth added $student_name</div>"."<BR>";



}


 ?>
```

if I deleted that student the text will be deleted too.

> John added Alan

how can I make it not to delete the text? And is there A better way to do it?

Comment: your not logging anything, just writing to output, it wont persist, why not log to another db table?

Comment: What about a table that stores events separately? Columns for event type, information specific to the event (student name, admin etc), and a timestamp.

Comment: Also look into using soft delete, and changing `auth` value to the id if the user (so you can link them still if the user changes their name), and add a `deleted_author`, `added_author` columns linking ids to the author who added or deleted them, then you got a log built in..

Comment: the 3 comments are helpful thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to write to a log file:

```php
<?php
$auth = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT c_id,student_name,auth FROM school WHERE auth = '{$auth}'";
$send_q = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(!$send_q){
  die('rip'.mysqli_error($connection));
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($send_q)){
    $c_id= $row['c_id'];
    $student_name= $row['student_name'];

    echo "<div class='font-w600'>$auth added $student_name</div>"."<BR>";

    # a+ means append mode
    # if you don't want others to read the log
    # make sure its outside the webserver's document root
    $logFile = fopen('path/to/log', 'a+');

    # Lock file (to prevent parallel writes)
    flock($logFile, LOCK_EX);

    fwrite($logFile, "$auth added $student_name".PHP_EOL);

    flock($logFile, LOCK_UN);

    fclose($logFile);
}

 ?>
```

If you want complex logging, you probably want to store it in the database.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I was looking for the "Complex logging" thingy

Comment: wring to a table is easier than a file